# SharePoint online When user clicks on New/edit item need to redirect to site page

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

Need to redirect to site page when user clicks on new/edit item in SharePoint online new experience, site page will have spfx app to add or edit item.

How could we achieve this functionality, in classic experience we will script editor or content editor web part but in new experience we can't edit the page.

Answer (score 2):

This is a new extension type built into SPFx with v1.15 (preview) called Form Customizer extension. You can find out details about how to implement custom forms using SPFx by watching this video (released this morning):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90DWB9hjo-k

Key Points for your scenario:

- Overriding item level form for Edit/New/View with SPFx
- Own the whole canvas with context
- Save and Close calls
- Actual availability of doing this in a production list is coming later this year (Rolling out between April and June 2022)

---

There is no supported way to do this in modern lists/libraries until this comes out. You can customize forms with Power Apps and do some customization with formatting expressions, body layout, and header/footer formats.